# Stupid escaping quotes question

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

I know this should be basic but for the life of me....

```
eventMouseover: function(calEvent, domEvent) {
    if (typeof calEvent.id != 'undefined'){
        var layer = "<div id='events-layer' class='fc-transparent' style='position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; top:-1px; text-align:right; z-index:100'> <a> <img border='0' style='padding-right:5px;' src='/icon_note_delete.png' width='16' onClick='deleteEvent("+calEvent.id+");'></a></div>";
        $(this).append(layer);
    }
}
```

The part that isn't working is

```
onClick='deleteEvent("+calEvent.id+");
```

Since the id will be a string not a number I need to quote it.

as is it is giving me

```
onClick="deleteEvent(e_1984_2_184_668)"
```

but I need

```
onClick="deleteEvent('e_1984_2_184_668')"
```

I have tried

```
onClick='deleteEvent(\'"+calEvent.id+"\');
```

but it didn't work either.  I know this is something stupid that I am missing but help is much appriecated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use double-quotes to surround `calEvent.id`, because it's within a single quote string:

```
var layer = "<div id='events-layer' class='fc-transparent' style='position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; top:-1px; text-align:right; z-index:100'> <a> <img border='0' style='padding-right:5px;' src='/icon_note_delete.png' width='16' onClick='deleteEvent(\""+calEvent.id+"\");'></a></div>";
```

However, it would be easier and more readable in my opinion if you used a chain of jQuery calls to create your HTML instead:

```
var layer = $('<div></div>').attr('id', 'events-layer')
                .addClass('fc-transparent')
                .css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    top: '-1px',
                    textAlign: 'right',
                    zIndex: '100'
                })
                .appendTo(this);

var anchor = $('<a></a>').appendTo(layer);

var img = $('<img>').attr('border', '0')
                    .attr('src', '/icon_note_delete.png')
                    .attr('width', '16')
                    .css({
                        paddingRight: '5px'                        
                    })
                    .click(function() { deleteEvent(calEvent.id); })
                    .appendTo(anchor);
```

Comment: This Worked! Thanks!!  I guess I thought onclick="deleteEvent("e_9884_2_127_561");" wouldn't work correctly since I always try to put params in a different type of quote than the call but even though it looks strange it works.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
 ... onClick='deleteEvent('" + calEvent.id + "'); ...
```

Comment: I tried that and I get the quotes all messed up  <img border="0" width="16" e_9884_2_127_561');'+"" onclick="deleteevent(" src="/icon_note_delete.png" style="padding-right: 5px">

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to flip the single and double quotes around ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8c4B/)):

```
var calEventId = 'testid';

var layer = '<div id="events-layer" class="fc-transparent" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; top:-1px; text-align:right; z-index:100"> <a> <img border="0" style="padding-right:5px;" src="/icon_note_delete.png" width="16" onClick="deleteEvent(\'' + calEventId + '\');"></a></div>';

alert(layer);
```

Then you can escape the single quotes, and the resulting HTML string looks more like that HTML you would see in everyday markup (double-quotes around attribute values, single-quotes in the JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using jQuery. I suggest to create the elements with jQuery:

```
$('<div />', {
     id: 'events-layer',
     'class': 'fc-transparent someClass',
}).append(
    $('<a />', {
         href: '<you need an href attribute>',
    }).append('<img />', {
        'class': 'someOtherClass',
        src: '/icon_note_delete.png',
        width: '16',
        click: function() {
            deleteEvent(calEvent.id);
        }
    })
).appendTo(this);
```

where `someClass` and  `someOtherClass` would be:

```
.someClass {
    position:absolute; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    top:-1px; 
    text-align:right; 
    z-index:100
} 

.someOtherClass {
    border: none;
    padding-right:5px;
    width: 16px;
}
```